# IN operator with SELECT clause fails

Tags: sql

The resultant error is:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Invalid column name 'Email'.
```

Code:

```
-- Bulk insert data from csv file into server temp table
BULK INSERT vwTemporaryIT_USE_ONLY_Import FROM 'C:\Bulk\b_email.csv' 
WITH (
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
Go 

-- Set the flag in db for all records imported from csv
UPDATE [APTIFY].[dbo].[Person]
   SET 
      [IT_Use_Only] = 1

  WHERE 
  [Email] IN

  (Select [Email] From vwTemporaryIT_USE_ONLY_Import)
Go
```

I can see that the `vwTemporaryIT_USE_ONLY_Import` table is being populated with the data from the CSV fine, but is seems the following statement is failing for some reason:

```
WHERE 
      [Email] IN

      (Select [Email] From vwTemporaryIT_USE_ONLY_Import)
```

I am certainly not an expert at this and I may not have setup the table or view correctly, as I recently added the `Email` column to both. But they have matching datatype of `nvchar(100) not null`. I have also tried it as null. I'm not even sure if `IN` handles `nvchar` such is the level of my SQL expertise. Any clues what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does your Person table and vwTemporaryIT_USE_ONLY_Import view has Email field ?

Comment: Actually no! In the `Person` table it was called `Email1`. I have changed the code to:


`WHERE [Email1] IN (Select [Email] From wTemporaryIT_USE_ONLY_Import)`

...and now it works fine. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Actually no! In the `Person` table it was called `Email1`. I have changed the code to:

`WHERE [Email1]`
`IN`

`(Select [Email] From wTemporaryIT_USE_ONLY_Import)`

...and now it works fine. Thanks for your help!!